# 2014 chevy cruze with turbo making a noise like im runnin in lower gear

Tags: chevrolet, noise, cruze

I have a 2014 Chevrolet Cruz with turbo. When I'm driving in regular drive it is making a noise like I'm driving in a lower gear.  I can hear the noise over my radio its so loud. I took it to Chevrolet mechanic.. He said it was my tires running on the road making the noise.I don't think it is.I think its something wrong with the engine. I'm trying to identify the noise or problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you hear it when you're standing still?If the noise is commensurate with your speed, it's something in the drive train. If it's something varies with engine speed, it's something to do with your engine.

Comment: Poor wheel alignment can wear tires in such a way (cupping) they can be very loud rolling down the road.